# Filter array of objects by keeping objects with matching key and also adjacent objects

Tags: javascript, filter

I found it difficult to phrase the title to describe the issue that I am having, however I hope that an example will be helpful. I have a javascript array of objects that looks something like this:

```
const myPlayer = "jim"
const myArray = 
    [
      {"player":"bob", "points":11},
      {"player":"joe", "points":15},
      {"player":"nik", "points":18},
      {"player":"tom", "points":21},
      {"player":"jim", "points":25},
      {"player":"ron", "points":26},
      {"player":"tim", "points":32},
      {"player":"jon", "points":35},
      {"player":"len", "points":42},
      {"player":"eva", "points":51}
    ];
```

My array sorts objects by the key **points**, and i would like to filter this array to keep (a) the object whose **player** key matches the *myPlayer* variable, as well as (b) the 2 objects before and the 2 objects after the object that matches the *myPlayer* variable. For example, in this case, I'd like to return the following:

```
const filtArray = 
    [
      {"player":"nik", "points":18},
      {"player":"tom", "points":21},
      {"player":"jim", "points":25},
      {"player":"ron", "points":26},
      {"player":"tim", "points":32}
    ];
```

...since nik and tom are the two objects before jim, and ron and tim are the two objects after tim. The **player** key will have a unique value for each object, so there will never be two objects with the same **player** key.

One last part to this question - I would like the filtered array to always contain 5 objects. Therefore, if `myPlayer = "bob"`, where bob is the **player** in the very first object, I would like it to simply return the first 5 objects, like so:

```
 [
  {"player":"bob", "points":11},
  {"player":"joe", "points":15},
  {"player":"nik", "points":18},
  {"player":"tom", "points":21},
  {"player":"jim", "points":25}
];
```

... with similar output if myPlayer = "joe", or if myPlayer = either "len" or "eva".

Any help with this is appreciated, thanks !!

Edit: Looks like I simply had a small bug in my code that was breaking my approach... have the following, which uses findIndex and slice:

```
const index = myArray.findIndex(x => x.player === myPlayer);    
filtArray = myArray.slice(index-2, index+2)
```

Comment: What have you tried? You're expected to try and if you need help then post specific questions... not "How do I do this"

Comment: Have tried to grab the array index where player matches myPlayer, and filter around that index using a for loop - give me a minute and can post what I've got.

Comment: The code you posted in your edit won't work for "bob," "joe," "len," or "eva" as per your description: `if  myPlayer = "bob", where bob is the player in the very first object, I would like it to simply return the first 5 objects`. For those on which it does "work," it only returns 4 objects, rather than 5 (the upper bound isn't included in the slice).

Answer (score 0):

You could do one `for loop` for the first part, and `slice()` for the second, but as you said if you select `eva` shows the first 5, if you want something different you could change just the slice.

```js
const myPlayer = "ron";
const myArray = [
  { player: "bob", points: 11 },
  { player: "joe", points: 15 },
  { player: "nik", points: 18 },
  { player: "tom", points: 21 },
  { player: "jim", points: 25 },
  { player: "ron", points: 26 },
  { player: "tim", points: 32 },
  { player: "jon", points: 35 },
  { player: "len", points: 42 },
  { player: "eva", points: 51 }
];

var newArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i].player == myPlayer){
      var index = i;//<-- store the index to probably be used in slice
    if ((i-2)>=0 && (i+2)<myArray.length) {
    newArray.push(myArray[i - 2]);
    newArray.push(myArray[i - 1]);
    newArray.push(myArray[i]);
    newArray.push(myArray[i + 1]);
    newArray.push(myArray[i + 2]);
  }
}
}

if(newArray.length == 0){
    newArray = myArray.slice(0, 6) 
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by finding the index of the player you are looking for, and then looping through the array and creating a new list of players with an index within that range.

```js
const myPlayer = "jim"
const myArray = [
    {"player":"bob", "points":11},
    {"player":"joe", "points":15},
    {"player":"nik", "points":18},
    {"player":"tom", "points":21},
    {"player":"jim", "points":25},
    {"player":"ron", "points":26},
    {"player":"tim", "points":32},
    {"player":"jon", "points":35},
    {"player":"len", "points":42},
    {"player":"eva", "points":51}
]

function indexOfPlayer(arr, player) {
    return arr.map(i => i.player).indexOf(player)
}

function getItemWithSurrounding(arr, index, around) {
    result = []
    for (i = index - around; i <= index + around; i++) {
        if (i >= 0 && i < arr.length) {
            result.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return result
}
playerIndex = indexOfPlayer(myArray, myPlayer)
players = getItemWithSurrounding(myArray, playerIndex, 2)
console.log(players)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "player": "nik",
    "points": 18
  },
  {
    "player": "tom",
    "points": 21
  },
  {
    "player": "jim",
    "points": 25
  },
  {
    "player": "ron",
    "points": 26
  },
  {
    "player": "tim",
    "points": 32
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.findIndex` method to locate the correct player in the array, then use `Array.slice` with a couple of if statements to select the correct segment of the array (either the first 5 if the first or second player is selected, the last 5 if one of the last two players is selected, or the five surrounding an "inner" player).

```js
const myPlayer = "jim"
const myArray = 
    [
      {"player":"bob", "points":11},
      {"player":"joe", "points":15},
      {"player":"nik", "points":18},
      {"player":"tom", "points":21},
      {"player":"jim", "points":25},
      {"player":"ron", "points":26},
      {"player":"tim", "points":32},
      {"player":"jon", "points":35},
      {"player":"len", "points":42},
      {"player":"eva", "points":51}
    ];

function filterArray(array, playerName) {
  let idx = array.findIndex(o => o.player === playerName)
  if (array.length - idx <= 2) {
    return array.slice(array.length - 5)
  } else if (idx < 2) {
    return array.slice(0, 5)
  } else {
    return array.slice(idx - 2, idx + 3)
  }
}

console.log(filterArray(myArray, myPlayer)) // "jim" is an "inner" player, so the surrounding elements are returned
console.log(filterArray(myArray, "joe")) // "joe" is an "outer" player, so the first five elements are returned
console.log(filterArray(myArray, "eva")) // "eva" is an "outer" player, so the last five elements are returned
```